# Making use of a PNG image in a NextJS app

Tags: firebase, image, next.js

I want to make use of an image (.png) in a NextJS app I am working on.
The app is hosted on Firebase.

I looked at this documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image.

I am also looking at this:
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-image-loader-config#example-loader-configuration

I see for example:

```
export default function akamaiLoader({ src, width, quality }) {
  return `https://example.com/${src}?imwidth=${width}`
}
```

But how am I supposed to use that?
Is example.com supposed to be replaced by some URL of mine?

I must say I have some hard time to make sense of all that.

I have tried this code:

```
<Image
  // loader={myLoader}
  src="../Images/edit.png"
  alt="Some picture of mine"
  width={100}
  height={100}
/>
```

I can ony see the message "Some picture of mine" appear but never the image itself.

Some relevant hints would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to make thing easier, if you want to use internal images, you should put them on the public folder since the folder is view as the route `/`.

- public/favicon.ico => `/favicon.ico`
- public/Images/edit.png => `/Images/edit.png`

you can then use them on the `NextImage` (`Images`) component like:

```
 <Image
  src='/Images/edit.png'
  alt="Some picture of mine"
  width={100}
  height={100}
 />
```

or you can [import the images staticaly](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/images#local-images) using relative or [absolute import](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/absolute-imports-and-module-aliases).

```
import editImg from '../Images/edit.png';

// ...
// in your component
  <Image
   src={editImg}
   alt="Some picture of mine"
   width={100}
   height={100}
  />
```

You will not need to use a custom loader unless you have some use case requiring it.